# find function string in c++

Tags: c++, string

If I want search first occurrence of letter in str1. If my str include both letter and number and symbol, but First I just want search location of letter like"a","b","c","d"...
can I create a string arr

```
string str[]={"a","b","c","d","e"....};
str1="signal a: a<= '0';";
str1.find(str,0);
```

can I do like this?

And I want to ask another question about string size

```
string str="signal a";
cout<<str.size()<<endl;
```

size of this string should be 8, but it actually just gives me 86?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/  When no matches are found, the function returns `string::npos`

Comment: How? in string which is"qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm" has "s" which is also first element of "signal"?

Comment: `str.find("qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm",0)` will search for the FULL sequence "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm" inside `str` starting at position 0.

Comment: so if I want to search each "a","b"....I need to use a array that use find? Can I just use str.find(arr,0)? which want search "a","b","c"...

Comment: Are you looking for [find_first_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of)?

Comment: Maybe you could give an example of what result you are expecting?

Comment: Yes. and I already add an example of what I need to do

Comment: What result do you want from that?

Comment: I want 0, the position when letter first occur

Comment: 4294967295 is equal to -1 in signed integer. you are using unsigned integer. -1 indicates that string was not found

Comment: http://ideone.com/BSkED8

Comment: sorry about that, I think that because i add more cout which output is 6